# SVG linear gradient in Firefox not shown

Tags: firefox, svg, gradient, linear-gradients, svg-filters

I have the following [code example](https://codepen.io/BuZZ-dEE/pen/gOpMzPZ) which uses SVG `linearGradient`, `rect` and `feImage` to show a linear gradient. The gradient is displayed correctly in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

What could be the problem and how can I correct it?

```html
<svg width="350" height="350" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>

<!-- INSTAGRAM ADEN FILTER -->
    <linearGradient id="gradient_aden">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#420A18" stop-opacity="100%" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#420A18" stop-opacity="0%" />
    </linearGradient>
    <!-- screen on filtered image -->
    <rect id="adensc" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity=".5" fill="url(#gradient_aden)" />
    <filter id="aden"
            color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
            filterUnits="objectBoundingBox"
            primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox"
            x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
        <!--hue-rotate -->
        <feColorMatrix type="hueRotate" values="-20"/>
        <!-- contrast -->
        <feComponentTransfer>
            <feFuncR type="linear" slope=".9" intercept="0.05"/>
            <feFuncG type="linear" slope=".9" intercept="0.05"/>
            <feFuncB type="linear" slope=".9" intercept="0.05"/>
        </feComponentTransfer>
        <!-- brightness -->
        <feComponentTransfer result="hcb">
            <feFuncR type="linear" slope="1.2"/>
            <feFuncG type="linear" slope="1.2"/>
            <feFuncB type="linear" slope="1.2"/>
        </feComponentTransfer>
        <!-- blend mode -->
        <feImage xlink:href="#adensc" result="grad" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        <feBlend mode="darken" in="hcb" />
    </filter>

</defs>

<image xlink:href="https://una.im/CSSgram/img/atx.jpg" id="image" x="0" y="0" width="612" height="413" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" filter="url(#aden)"/>  

<image xlink:https://una.im/CSSgram/img/atx.jpg" id="image0" x="612" y="0" width="612" height="413" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />  

</svg>
```

Comment: Firefox doesn't support fragment identifiers as inputs to feImage - so xlink:href="#adensc" is not supported. You have to inline the content as a data URI (a real pain).

Comment: @MichaelMullany thx for your comment. There is no other solution to this problem?

Comment: There is not. You have to create a separate SVG image with the rect & gradient and inline it as a svg+xml data:uri - which can be finicky to get right. aka - xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg%20version%3..... etc.